# NuGet package manager marks target platform as unsupported

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-standard

I've created NuGet package from .Net Standard 1.3 library. Package definition in csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Summary>My package</Summary>
        <Description>My package description</Description>   
        <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
        <Authors>Opensoft Inc.</Authors>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;</TargetFrameworks>
        <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.3</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
        <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETStandard</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.3</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <AssemblyName>TestAssembly</AssemblyName>
        <PackageIconUrl></PackageIconUrl>
        <PackageProjectUrl></PackageProjectUrl>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But after publishing package, I can't reference it correctly from .Net Framework 4.6.1 web application project. It says that target platform is unsupported.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got some stray property definitions in your csproj file.

Remove the properties `TargetFrameworkIdentifier` and `TargetFrameworkVersion` as well as `NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion`.

Only keep `TargetFrameworks` (and remove the stray `;` at the end), and let the tooling do its job to figure out the correct values for all other properties to be able to publish a correct nuget package.

Note that if you publish a "corrected" package, you will need to either change the version number or clear the local package cache on all machines that already downloaded the corrupt package (=> `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`).